# NSiS call a function to dump log file at the end of installation

Tags: function, installation, nsis

im working on a project where im using NSI to create a setup **myproject.exe**,
everything works fine, but i want to dump the log that is displayed into a file, that also works fine, but my problem is i cant figure out when to call the log function

i have 12 sections in my script  , i got the function to create the installation log from [Dump log to file](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Dump_log_to_file)

```
 !define PRODUCT_NAME "myApplication"
 !define PRODUCT_VERSION "1.7.1"
 !define LVM_GETITEMCOUNT 0x1004
 !define LVM_GETITEMTEXT 0x102D
 !include MUI2.nsh


  Name "myExe"
  OutFile "C:\myExe.exe"

  InstallDir $PROGRAMFILES\myprojc
  InstallDirRegKey HKCU "Software\myprojc" "Install_Dir"

  !define MUI_ABORTWARNING      
  !define MUI_ICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\Folder-Options.ico"
  !define MUI_UNICON "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Icons\orange-uninstall.ico"
  !define MUI_HEADERIMAGE
  !define MUI_HEADERIMAGE_BITMAP "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\Banner.bmp" 

    ; Pages

  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
  !insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES

   !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_WELCOME
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
  !insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_FINISH

    ;Languages

 !insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE "English"
 BrandingText "myProj version 1.7.1"

 ;Here My section are decribed.. 12 of them
 Section "main program and components" section1
     ;main promgram files are copied

 SectionEnd

 Section "other DLL" section2
 ;copy the DLLs
 SectionEnd

 Section "Text files" section3
 ;copy the required txt files
 SectionEnd

  ;-....
  ;...

 Section "install BDE admin" section12
  ;copy install BDE admin

    ;Calling the Dumplog function to create the log file
     StrCpy $0 "$INSTDIR\Query\Presleyinstall.log"
     Push $0
     Call DumpLog
 SectionEnd


;The function dumps the to a log file
 Function DumpLog
 Exch $5
 Push $0
 Push $1
 Push $2
 Push $3
 Push $4
 Push $6

 FindWindow $0 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
 GetDlgItem $0 $0 1016
StrCmp $0 0 exit
FileOpen $5 $5 "w"
StrCmp $5 "" exit
SendMessage $0 ${LVM_GETITEMCOUNT} 0 0 $6
System::Alloc ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}
Pop $3
StrCpy $2 0
System::Call "*(i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i, i) i \
  (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, r3, ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}) .r1"
loop: StrCmp $2 $6 done
  System::Call "User32::SendMessageA(i, i, i, i) i \
    ($0, ${LVM_GETITEMTEXT}, $2, r1)"
  System::Call "*$3(&t${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN} .r4)"
  FileWrite $5 "$4$\r$\n"
  IntOp $2 $2 + 1
  Goto loop
done:
  FileClose $5
  System::Free $1
  System::Free $3
exit:
  Pop $6
  Pop $4
  Pop $3
  Pop $2
  Pop $1
   Pop $0
  Exch $5
FunctionEnd
```

Since i have called the **dumplog** function in **section 12**, the log file is **only** create when/if the section is selected by the user, if the section 12 is not selected then the dumplog function wont be called and log file will not be created,

so please tell me how do i call the dumplog function irrespective of the section is selected or not by the user, That is call the dumplog when the installation is complete.

**EDIT**

i can also try to create a section "Create installer log" and check it and disable like

```
 Section "Create installer log" section13
 SectionIn RO
 StrCpy $0 "$INSTDIR\myinstall.log"
 Push $0
 Call DumpLog
 SectionEnd
```

this [image]

but is there a way to call the dumplog function without section, and at the end of the installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't give the section a name (or start the name with `-`) then it will not be displayed on the components page:

```
Section "Foobar"
;Install the optional Foobar
SectionEnd

Section
;Hidden section
Section
```

Answer (score 1):

You can even put it in callback functions.

```
Function .onInstSuccess
;..
Call DumpLog
;..
FunctionEnd

Function .onInstFail
;..
Call DumpLog
;..
FunctionEnd
```